# Problem with ${ViewsUrl} in my Alchemy Plugin

Tags: gui-extensions, a4t

In my alchemy plugin i'm using the following code reference my HTML popup

```
"${ViewsUrl}File.html";
```

When installing this generates the following URL:

```
/WebUI/Editors/Alchemy/Plugins/My_Plugin/assets/views/File.html
```

So I would expect to see File.html in the /assets/views directory.

Instead I see the File.html inside the `Assets` folder, the '`Views`' folder is not part of my generated plugin folder.

I suspect this is a bug for HTML files? as this works perfectly with ASPX files.

I'm using Alchemy 0.8 if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently by design, only .aspx pages get put into the /assets/views/ folder, as only aspx pages can take advantage of the resource groups.  You can change your filename to .aspx, and Alchemy will automatically inject the directives and controls necessary.

If you don't need to utilize any resource groups and prefer to leave it as .html, you can also use the `${AssetsUrl}` token instead:

```
"${AssetsUrl}File.html";
```

Hope that helps!